# Emacs is not recognizing R scripts as commands I could see only text lines

Tags: emacs, r

I am using Emacs for R when I type in R scripts I could see only text lines and not as scripts so eventually I could not able to run. I saved the work sheet with *.R extension. Please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Obviously emacs is not an R interpreter (it's a lisp interpreter), though there is the ESS package available to integrate R (and others) with syntax highlighting, and sub-processes for evaluation.

However in a plain emacs you can edit your scripts, then call up a shell `M-x shell return` to run them with `R script_file.R` which you would have to have installed separately anyway and thus would have available to you on the command line.